# PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method PDOStatement::rowCount()

Tags: php, pdo

I am trying to get the rowCount() function. But its throwing an error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method PDOStatement::rowCount()

I am not sure where is the problem.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = :username";
$statement = $connect->prepare($query);
$statement->execute(
    array(
        ':username' => $_POST["username"]
    )
);
$count = $statement->rowCount();
```

Comment: Although this error message is improbable and mysterious, I just want to note that the rowCount() function being essentially useless and as a quick workaround you can just get rid of it. just fetch the selected data using fetch() and use it instead.

Comment: Yes i understand. Can you do me a favour by showing an example. Thx

Comment: example of what? of using fetch? $row= $statement->fetch();

Comment: Sure i will try. Thank you